# Why maven puts provided dependency?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I created a simple project

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Next, I ran

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Results:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ asd ---
[INFO] sdddas:asd:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-mvc-jsp:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO]    +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO]    |     +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO]    |     +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO]    |     \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-mvc:jar:2.23.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO]    \- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then

```
mvn package
```

As result I see war file with servlet-api-2.4.jar in WEB-INF/lib

Why? If I look at jersey-mvc-jsp.pom, I see

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>${servlet2.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I define the same dependency in my pom file, set scope to provided, and now my war file does not contain servlet-api-2.4.jar. But I still don't understand why maven put it there

Comment: It's listed as a transitive dependency of `jersey-mvc.jar`, is it also scoped as provided in that pom.xml?

Comment: @azurefrog no. In jersey-mvc it scoped as compile. So, if it scoped as compile in transitive of transitive dependency (where it was overrided as provided) it will appear in our package. And we must to override it as provided. Again. Ok. Thanks